# Plugin.InAppBilling always returns "Invalid Product" on Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin

I have been trying to implement the [Plugin.InAppBilling](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/InAppBillingPlugin) NuGet package for the last weeks and trying to run the "Get Product Details" example from the [documentation page](https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/InAppBillingPlugin/GetProductDetails.html).
However, the line

```
var items = await billing.GetProductInfoAsync(ItemType.InAppPurchase, productIds);
```

always throws the "PurchaseError.InvalidProduct" Exception.
I am quite sure that everything is set up correctly within AppStoreConnect and that I have followed the documentation exactly.
I am trying to implement this for a [MonoGame](https://www.monogame.net/) application, which uses Xamarin to host the app, which is why I am using the recommended Version "5.3.2-beta" of the InAppBilling-Plugin.
Is this a common error or are there any known workarounds?
Best Regards,
Dokug

Comment: Where do you get this recommended version from? Latest version is 6.3.3-beta and latest stable is 4.0.2

Comment: From [here](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/InAppBillingPlugin#important-version-information):
"For Xamarin.Forms and pre-.NET 6 it is recommended to use version 5.x"

Comment: 5.3.3 was just published yesterday

Comment: Thanks for that information, I'll check it out and see if the problem fixes itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plugin.InAppBilling Version 5.3.3-beta resolved this problem.